# what is the shell script command to checkout a project from github

Tags: shell, github, jenkins, sh, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running a Jenkins job on a GitHub project `(Project A)`, as part of this job I want to checkout another different GitHub project `(Project B)` using shell script command

Comment: How about git submodule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use a shell command for that you could go for

`$ git clone https://<YOUR_REPOSITORY_URL>`.

However, if you are using a Jenkins pipeline job you might consider using following command in your Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('Checkout') {
   git branch: '<BRANCH_NAME>', credentialsId: '<JENKINS_CREDENTIAL_ID>', url: 'git@<URL_OF_REPOSITORY>'
}
```